# What is the maximum length of the Push Notification Alert text?

Tags: java, android, ios, react-native, push-notification

I am developing an Android and IOS App.

I am currently developing an App with **Push Notification** enabled and I have a few questions. I don't know about Android, but in case of iOS, I know that the maximum length of the text for notification is up to **256 bytes**. Is there any change for this now? Is the text length is different for different versions?  What is the **maximum length** for Android?

Comment: both have same limit for send data in push

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS 8 and later, the maximum size allowed for a notification payload is 2 kilobytes; Apple Push Notification service refuses any notification that exceeds this limit. (Prior to iOS 8 and in OS X, the maximum payload size is 256 bytes.)

For Android: Notification messages can contain an optional data payload. Maximum payload for both message types is 4KB

Answer (score 0):

There is no official limits documented till now but, as it mentioned on IOS documentation you have given 2 kilobytes otherwise it will be refused by the system. for IOS 8 it will accept only 256 bytes.